# Label stopping from clicking input text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make floating input label which will float top when the input text area is focus. However, I ran into a problem where I can't click the input field because label is block me. There is small portion that I can press which is hard. Below I have shown my important code.

```css
.form {
    background-color: hsl(0, 63%, 72%);
    padding: 2em 4em;
}

.form-group {
    transition: all .3s;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.form-label {
    font-size: 1em;
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.8;
    transform: translateY(-1.25em);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transition: all .3s;
    z-index: -999;
}

.form-control {
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0,0.02);
    border-radius: 0px;
    border-color: white;
    border-style: none none solid none;
    width: 100%;
    transition: all .5s;
}

.form-control::placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}

.form-control:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
    border-color: orange;
}

.form-control:focus + .form-label,
.form-control:not(:placeholder-shown) + .form-label {
    transform: translateY(-2.5em) scale(.8);
}

.form-control:focus-within {
    transform: scale(1.05,1.05);
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"></inpu>
        <label for="name" class="form-label">Username</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text"  placeholder="Password" class="form-control" class="form-label"></inpu>
        <label for="Password" class="form-label">Password</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You have a typo in your closing `input` tag - i.e. `</input>` (which, btw, it is not needed) - I put the code into a running snippet and it seems to run fine.  Can you expand on what exactly is not working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `display: block` you can define `display: inline-block` for the label if `pointer-events: none` is no option for you. Though the small part of the label text then still will be not clickable, for the rest of the input it works...

**Working example:**

```css
.form {
    background-color: hsl(0, 63%, 72%);
    padding: 2em 4em;
}

.form-group {
    transition: all .3s;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.form-label {
    font-size: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0.8;
    transform: translateY(-1.25em);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transition: all .3s;
    z-index: -999;
}

.form-control {
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0,0.02);
    border-radius: 0px;
    border-color: white;
    border-style: none none solid none;
    width: 100%;
    transition: all .5s;
}

.form-control::placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}

.form-control:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
    border-color: orange;
}

.form-control:focus + .form-label,
.form-control:not(:placeholder-shown) + .form-label {
    transform: translateY(-2.5em) scale(.8);
}

.form-control:focus-within {
    transform: scale(1.05,1.05);
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"></inpu>
        <label for="name" class="form-label">Username</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text"  placeholder="Password" class="form-control" class="form-label"></inpu>
        <label for="Password" class="form-label">Password</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: For learning to code i started with https://www.w3schools.com/, since there is nearly always a "try it" section where you can try the code and change it and play arround with it and after a click on "Run" you see the result...

Answer (score 0):

If the label is blcoking you from clicking on your textarea, **and** you would not want to click on the label for any reason, you can use:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

On the label such that any clicks will pass through it.

Comment: wow that helped..thanks can u tell me how to learn css ? i wanna learn more about such commands

Comment: There are countless CSS tutorials you can find on the internet. MDN is a good place to start. If you are the type of person who prefers to learn with videos, YouTube has all you need. Finally, you may mark this answer as "accepted" if it solves your problem. Happy learning!